# AWS app very slow and laggy despite low CPU instance usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, plotly-dash

I have a small dash app running on a t3.medium EC2 instance connected to an AWS RDS with a single user. Running the app locally has no problems and the app is very responsive. I checked the CPU resources (attached) and while using the app, the utilization appeared low. Connection to RDS doesn't not appear to be laggy, however, any triggered callbacks are very slow. Could something like this be caused by not utilizing CloudFront? I switched back from HTTPS to HTTP, with modest improvement. Thanks

[image: t3.medium instance performance during app usage]

Comment: "any triggered callbacks" - what callbacks? Can you provide more info what your app is doing? Maybe is RAM heavy, or relies on some external API which is slow? Is your app slow all the time, or there is some pattern to it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have updated the question regarding the callbacks. The app loads reasonable quickly but is slow throughout usage and I don't see any performance issues as the dataset increases. I am using the AWS Ohio-east server and live in the West coast..so perhaps the transiting of data is taking time? I will check the ram usage. Oddly enough, I've had little issue with Heroku.

Comment: Thank for your help. I think I may have found the answer. The internet bandwidth was low.